# Prove inequality without using Möbius transformations

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Is there a simple way to prove the following inequality **without using** Möbius transformations:

$\left| \frac{{z}_{1}-{z}_{3}}{1-{z}_{3}\bar{{z}_{1}}} \right| \leq \left| \frac{{z}_{1}-{z}_{2}}{1-{z}_{2}\bar{{z}_{1}}} \right| + \left| \frac{{z}_{2}-{z}_{3}}{1-{z}_{3}\bar{{z}_{2}}} \right|$,

where ${z}_{i}$ is a complex number and  $\left|{z}_{i}\right|<1$ holds for $i=1,2,3$

*(This would be my approach if I were to prove the inequality by **using** a Möbius Transformation:
Use the hyperbolic metric $d({z}_{1},z_{2})=2tanh^{-1}\left| \frac{{z}_{1}-{z}_{2}}{1-{z}_{2}\bar{{z}_{1}}} \right|$. Apply the Möbius Transformation $\phi(x)=\frac{{z}_{1}-x}{1-x\bar{{z}_{1}}}$ so now we have $d(0,\phi(z_{2}))=d({z}_{1},z_{2})$. By combining this result and the fact that $d$ is a metric (so the triangle inequality holds) and tanh is bijective it should be easy to prove the above inequality.)*

Comment: How do you prove this using Möbius transformations?

Comment: The missing item is the proof that $d$ satisfies the triangle inequality; once that is proven, the inequality you want is an immediate consequence of the convexity and monotonicity of $\tanh^{-1}$; see my answer. However, I have no idea on how to prove that, either with or without Möbius transformations.

Answer (score 1):

This is the completion of your idea of using the hyperbolic distance function
$$
d(z_1, z_2)=2\tanh^{-1}\left\lvert \frac{z_1-z_2}{1-z_2\overline{z_1}}\right\rvert.$$

To begin, we note that the hyperbolic arctangent is **superadditive** for nonnegative arguments;
$$
\tanh^{-1}(x+y)\ge \tanh^{-1}(x)+\tanh^{-1}(y),\qquad \forall x, y\in[0, 1).$$
(This follows from the fact that $\tanh^{-1}$ is convex, increasing, and that $\tanh^{-1}(0)=0$; see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/523747/8157)).
Combining the triangle inequality for $d$ and this superadditivity, we have that
$$
\begin{split}
\tanh^{-1}\left\lvert \frac{z_1-z_2}{1-z_2\overline{z_1}}\right\rvert&\le\tanh^{-1}\left\lvert \frac{z_1-z_3}{1-z_3\overline{z_1}}\right\rvert+\tanh^{-1}\left\lvert \frac{z_3-z_2}{1-z_2\overline{z_3}}\right\rvert \\ &\le\tanh^{-1}\left(\left\lvert \frac{z_1-z_3}{1-z_3\overline{z_1}}\right\rvert + \left\lvert \frac{z_3-z_2}{1-z_2\overline{z_3}}\right\rvert\right),
\end{split} $$
hence the claim, since $\tanh^{-1}$ is increasing.