# A question on convexity of $\psi$ to prove $\Vert X \Vert_{C\psi} \leq C \Vert X \Vert_{\psi}$ for Orlicz norms

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, orlicz-spaces

I have come across an apparently simple exercise on Orlicz norms (exercise 2.2.3 of Van der Vaart's "Weak convergence and Empirical processes") which I cannot fully understand.

One has to show that, for any constant $C\geq 1$, random variable $X$, and convex, increasing function $\psi$, it holds that

$$\Vert X \Vert _{C\psi} \leq C \Vert X \Vert _{\psi}$$

It is suggested to use the fact that, being $\psi$ convex, we have

$$\mathbb{E}[\psi(\vert X \vert/C\Vert X \Vert_{\psi})] \leq 1/C \quad (\star)$$

Using this hint, solving the exercise is straightforward. In fact

$$ \Vert X \Vert_{C\psi} := \inf \Bigg\lbrace K > 0 \, : \, \mathbb{E} \bigg[C\psi\bigg(\frac{\vert X \vert}{K} \bigg) \bigg] \leq 1 \Bigg\rbrace = \inf \Bigg\lbrace K > 0 \, : \, \mathbb{E} \bigg[\psi\bigg(\frac{\vert X \vert}{K} \bigg) \bigg] \leq \frac{1}{C} \Bigg\rbrace$$

and so, thanks to $(\star)$, it follows that $\Vert X \Vert_{C\psi}\leq C\Vert X \Vert_{\psi}$.

**My question is:** how to prove $(\star)$? It does not seem obvious to me (maybe because I am quite rusty on convex functions...)

Clearly we have that $\mathbb{E}[\psi(\vert X \vert/\Vert X \Vert_{\psi})] \leq 1$, by definition of Orlicz norm. If for instance it were possible to show that  $\psi(ax)\leq a\psi(x), \forall x, \forall a \in (0,1]$, then $(\star )$ would follow. In the special case $\psi(x)=x^p$, $p\geq1$, or more in general if $\psi$ is $p$-homogeneous, then the previous inequality holds.

Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to extend this to general $\psi$ with the required properties (if it is true). Any suggestions? Many thanks!

**P.S.:** In the definition of Orlicz norm it is also assumed that $\psi(0)=0$.

Comment: Every convex, increasing function $\psi$ such that $\psi(0)=0$ is *superadditive* : $\psi(x+y) \geq \psi(x)+\psi(y)$. For a sketch of the proof (easily expanded into a full proof), see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/523747). You can use this to derive what you need, probably. For example, take $C = n$ for some integer $n$. Then write $C=\frac pq$ where $p,q$ are positive integers, and finally extend to the positive reals using the continuity of $\psi$.